# Simplifying nested ifs with multiple exit points in Scala?

Tags: scala, if-statement, return

There has to be a better way to do this.. I'm testing for a ray-triangle intersection and my code looks something like this

```
if(some condition) fail
else {
   ...
   if(some other condition) fail
   else {
      ...
      intersection
   }
}
```

with many nested ifs. It's disgusting. I'm doing this not to use any return statements. Is there an alternate control structure I could use here to manage the various method exit points?

Comment: Do the `...` do computations that are used in the conditions? If so, you may be stuck with either a chained or nested sequence of conditionals.

Comment: Yes, the `...` serve to determine if I need to go on to the next intersection test or if I can disqualify it then and there

Comment: Not necessarily recommending this but else `if  {....; some other condition} fail` might reduce the nesting a bit. difficult to tell if it's a reasonable idea without a more concrete example.

Comment: Why is it disgusting? Without a more concrete example is difficult to say.

Comment: The code I'm referring to is here: https://github.com/FabriceCastel/scala-raytracer/blob/master/src/main/scala/primitive/Triangle.scala

Comment: Code looks OK. I'd change the `if(t > Utils.EPSILON)` so that all `if`s were `if (condition) fail` for consistency.

Comment: Use `return`, problem solved.

Comment: **"I'm doing this not to use any return statements"**

I'm writing this as an exercise in functional programming, using `return` would go directly against what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This tutorial talks about nested ifs and equivalent code in functional style: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mw_Jnn_Y5iA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use for comprehension:

```
val result: Option[BasicIntersection] = for {
  edge1 <- Some(vertices(1) - vertices(0))
  edge2 = vertices(2) - vertices(0)
  P = ray.v cross edge2
  determinant = edge1 dot P
  if !(determinant > -Utils.EPSILON && determinant < Utils.EPSILON)
  inv_determinant = 1.0/determinant
  T = ray.p - vertices(0)
  u = (T dot P) * inv_determinant
  if !(u < 0 || u > 1)
  Q = T cross edge1
  v = (ray.v dot Q) * inv_determinant
  if !(v < 0 || u + v > 1)
  t = (edge2 dot Q) * inv_determinant
  if !(t < Utils.EPSILON)
  hit = ray.p + ray.v*t
} yield
  if (hasUV) {
    val d0 = Math.abs((hit - vertices(0)).length)
    val d1 = Math.abs((hit - vertices(1)).length)
    val d2 = Math.abs((hit - vertices(2)).length)
    val uvAvg = (uv(0)*d0 + uv(1)*d1 + uv(2)*d2) / (d0 + d1 + d2)
    new BasicIntersection(hit, edge1 cross edge2, t, uvAvg)
  } else {
    new BasicIntersection(hit, edge1 cross edge2, t)
  }

result.getOrElse(new BasicIntersection()) // Your failure case
```

Comment: ....except it doesn't actually work and throws a long string of exceptions starting at `not found: value P` :|

Comment: @FabCastel Sorry, I didn't compile this code. If you replace uppercase `val`s by lowercase ones it should work. Also, `T` and `t` will conflict so you will have to rename one of them.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this slowed down my render speed by approx 2x factor, which is a little on the insane side. Any idea as to why that is?